# Short exact sequence involving ring of polynomials C[x,y] and a ideal (x,y)

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and a ideal $(x,y)$. Show that exists a short exact sequence of R-modules
$$0\to R\to R^2\to(x,y)\to 0$$

I know that I have to prove that there is a injective homomorphism $f$ between $R$ and $R^2$ and a surjective homomorphism $g$ between $R^2$ and $(x,y)$ such that $\text{Im}f=\ker g $. The first thing I thought was to take the inclusion map from $R$ to $R^2$ but i can't think of any surjective mapping between $R^2$ and $(x,y)$

Comment: $R^2$ is a free module, so any homomorphism with it as the domain is determined by where it sends the generators. It has two generators; where might you send them? (By the way, what do you mean by "the projection from $R$ to $R^2$"?)

Comment: with projection i mean, if $a\in R$ then $(a,0) \in R\times R$ or $(a,a)\in R^2$ i don't know if i do a mistake with this

Comment: It's just the wrong terminology; we would call that an inclusion map. It's not really a big deal to mix up, but in general products have projection maps and coproducts have inclusions.

Comment: I would think instead in terms of just one map. If you can find an $R$-module surjection $R^2\to (a,b)$, then the kernel is automatically an $R$-module. If $R$ were a PID, the kernel would automatically be free, so you'd basically be done. The point of this problem is that $R$ is famously *not* a PID. As John said, try defining a map $R^2\to (a,b)$ in terms of generators and see if you can prove the kernel is isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: I can't see it, I'm stuck it

Comment: The ideal $(x,y)$ i can see it how $R[x]+R[y]$? and a basis for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ over itself i can't understand

Comment: Can you write how a general element of $(x,y)$ looks like ? It will help you find the map $R^2\to (x,y)$. Btw, you should first try to find this map before the other one.

Comment: an element of (x,y) looks like $\mathbb{C}[x,y]\dot x+\mathbb{C}[x,y]\dot y$ i.e an element of $(x,y)$ seems like how $xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)$ and i think in a map $R^2 \to (x,y)$ such that $(f(x,y),g(x,y)) \to xf(0,y)+yg(x,0).$ i'm not sure about all this

Comment: @Choosen No, why did you put zeroes ? you said an element of $(x,y)$ is of the form $xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)$, so the map is just $(f(x,y),g(x,y))\mapsto xf(x,y)+yg(x,y)$. This is obviously surjective. Now, what is the kernel of this map ? Find a generator to find a map from $R$ to this kernel.